# How to set width and height for AlertDialog box in Xamarin android c#?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin-studio

Can anyone show me how to set width and height for alert dialog box in xamarin C#. i have set a layout for dialogbox but it shows the layout with width shorted. Below is my code, advance thanks guys. i tried for looking all i can find is for android java platform.

Code:

```
var alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alert.SetView(LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SuccessPage, null));
                alert.Create().Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the *Window*-Property to get access to the layout-dimensions:

```
alert.Window.SetLayout(400, 450);
```

Another way to archive your goal would be to override the style of the alertDialog via XML, however you didn't showed your markup that you have written so far.

Answer (score -1):

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(ChatActivity.this);
                final View deleteDialogView = factory.inflate(
                        R.layout.current_location_map_dialog, null); 
                final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ChatActivity.this).create();
                alertDialog.setView(deleteDialogView);
   alertDialog.setCancelable(true); 
                alertDialog.show();
                alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);



    Hope this will work for you .I use xml of desired size in android for alert dialog
```